# Nuxt+i18n, How to make a root path to language selector page?

Tags: url, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I am building multilingual Server Side Rendering app with Nuxtjs 2.

I am also using nuxt-i18n package.

I want a build a static page on (/) root path. This root path should have no language. The link of each lang path will located on here.

Then the app will be start prefix strategy like,

```
/en

/es

/tr
```

Here is my nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  i18n: {
    strategy: 'prefix',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    langDir: '~/locales/',
    rootRedirect: null,
    vuex: {
      moduleName: 'i18n',
      syncRouteParams: true
    },
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en/en.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'tr',
        iso: 'tr',
        name: 'Türkçe',
        file: 'tr/tr.js'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When i am going to (/) root path, app redirecting me to /en (default lang). How to prevent redirect to default home and create specified page to here?

Answer (score -1):

did you try set `defaultLocale` to `null` or to remove it? i think in combination with `rootRedirect` it should then work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It doesn't work. I think, i can be able make it only on nginx configuration.